# Polymer core-input not rendering

Tags: polymer

I have code as follows:

```
<body unresolved>
  <core-header-panel>
   <core-toolbar layout horizontal center>
    <h1 flex>Title</h1>
    <a href="#" class="middle indent">Users</a>
    <a href="#" class="middle indent">Terms</a>
  </core-toolbar>

  <div class="container" layout horizontal>
    <core-input placeholder="Placeholder text here"></core-input>
  </div>
 </core-header-panel>
</body>
```

The problem is that my core-input component doesn't get rendered. The core-header panel and core-toolbar do, but the core-input doesn't. It gets a width and height of 0px. Even if I assign width and height to it, it renders with nothing inside. I'm loading all components using imports.

Am I missing something?

Imports are:

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../custom-components/admin-users.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-input/core-input.html">
```

Chrome is version 38.

Comment: Can you show your imports? What browser are you rendering on?

Comment: Everything else renders - even paper-input, but core-input doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-header-panel/index.html):

> **Important**: The core-header-panel will not display if its parent does not have a height.

Styling the core-header-panel with the appropriate height and width properties will display the placeholder. [Live Demo available here](https://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/#3e1190fa34eef5c46522).

Update your HTML imports to include core-toolbar:

```
  <link rel="import" href="../components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../components/core-input/core-input.html">
```

And add this styling on the same page as your HTML imports:

```
<style>
  core-header-panel {
    width: 360px;
    height: 400px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<core-input placeholder="Placeholder text here"></core-input>
```

with

```
<input is="core-input" placeholder="Placeholder text here">
```